# pgfplotstable: String replace in a table with meta-data from another table (using a foreachloop)

Tags: pgfplotstable, strings

I have a main-table `Data.txt` with some contents

```
col1, col2, col3
a, b, c
x, y, z
aaa, abc, xyz
```

where I want to replace some strings.

If I say

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{x,y,z}{
\pgfplotstableset{string replace={#1}{was #1}  }  
} % works
```

it works well.

But if I use another table `MetaData.txt`

```
actual, target
a, 1
b, 2
c, 3
```

with which I want to replace 'actual' with 'target' in the main-table

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,2}{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{#1}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\n}{actual}\of\MetaData%
\xdef\actual{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\n}{target}\of\MetaData%
\xdef\target{\pgfplotsretval}%
Let's replace: \actual, \target
% Problem here: 
\pgfplotstableset{  string replace={\actual}{\target}  }  % works not!
}%
```

the string replace of the main-table does not work!

*Note that these are arbitrary examples, instead of replacing 'a' with '1' it could be also the replacement from 'u' with 'whatever'.*

What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-Data.txt}
col1, col2, col3
a, b, c
x, y, z
aaa, abc, xyz
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-MetaData.txt}
actual, target
a, 1
b, 2
c, 3
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotstableset{string type, col sep=comma}
\begin{document}
\section{Original Table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\jobname-Data.txt}

\section{String Replaced Table}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{x,y,z}{
\pgfplotstableset{string replace={#1}{was #1}  }  
} % works

\pgfplotstableread[]{\jobname-MetaData.txt}\MetaData

% Problem: 
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,2}{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{#1}

\pgfplotstablegetelem{\n}{actual}\of\MetaData%
\xdef\actual{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\n}{target}\of\MetaData%
\xdef\target{\pgfplotsretval}%
Let's replace: \actual, \target
% Problem here: 
\pgfplotstableset{  string replace={\actual}{\target}  }  % works not!
}% 

\bigskip
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\jobname-Data.txt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All time the same. :)

```
% Problem here solved: 
\edef\temp{\noexpand\pgfplotstableset{  string replace={\actual}{\target}  }  }
\temp
```